# What is the difference between any and find in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get the set values from closure in groovy:

```
myList(1, 2, 3).any { it > 2 }
myList(1, 2, 3).find { it > 2 }
```

So not able to figure out, which one to use and better.

Comment: Depends on your requirements. Seems like just trying it would answer your question, no?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`any` returns boolean - true if any of the elements on the list matches the closure condition, while `find` returns first element that meets the criteria in closure being passed.

If you need to know if there're elements matching certain criteria, use `any`, if you need only a single element (the first one) use, `find`, if you need all the elements that matches the closure passed use `findAll`.

Example:

```
assert [1, 2, 3].any { it > 1 }
assert [1, 2, 3].find { it > 1 } == 2
assert [1, 2, 3].findAll { it > 1 } == [2, 3]
```